# How to use java Runtime to execute redis background

Tags: java, redis

I use this method `call_shell()` to connect Java and shell.

```
private static String call_shell(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        if(proc.waitFor() != 0){
            System.out.println("wrong in shell.");
        } 
        String s = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(s).append("\r\n");
        }
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

However, when I call this method using `System.out.println(call_shell("/usr/local/bin/redis-server"));`, it will get blocked on the console, because of `redis-server` will block the bash.

So I use `System.out.println(call_shell("/usr/local/bin/redis-server &"));` and want to run it background. However, it turns out an error which is

```
wrong in shell.
24759:C 21 Apr 16:45:47.718 # Fatal error, can't open config file '&'
```

How can I run it background?

Comment: It blocks because you tell Java to `waitFor` process to finish, not because something blocks the command line (which it doesn't). If you want backround task, you need to not call the waitFor. Which subsequently means you can not return string from there anymore, you will have to return inputStream.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.